# Consider we use a single lock variable to solve the mutual exclusion problem as in the code below?

Tags: operating-system

```
boolean lock = false;
  // in thread 1
     while (true) {
     if (lock) {
          lock = true;
          criticalRegion1();
          lock = false;
            }    
        }
        // in thread 2
            while (true) {
                if (!lock) {
                    lock = true;
                    criticalRegion(2);
                    lock = false;
        }
    }
```

Does this work correctly? If yes, explain how. If no, describe how the program can execute resulting in a race condition?

Answer (score 1):

This is a homework question. To find the right answer for this (and for most things involving race conditions in general):

Break the code that each thread does into "atomic pieces". For example, something like `x++;` should be considered three steps (`temp = x; temp++; x = temp;` where `temp` is a register and not a variable). Forget about things that don't have globally visible state (e.g. accessing a local variable isn't important because a different thread won't care, but accessing a global variable is important because a different thread will see or effect it).

Next; imagine every possible order that these "important atomic pieces" could be done in; and see if there's a problem.

For example, if one thread has 2 atomic pieces A and B; and if the other thread has 2 atomic pieces C and D; then you would want to consider:

```
A, B, C then D
A, C, B then D
C, A, B then D
A, C, D then B
C, A, D then B
C, D, A then B
```

*Note: This sounds like a lot of work at first; but it won't take much practice before you're able to quickly skip "not likely to be a problem" cases and focus on "more likely to be a problem" cases.*